# How can I check the Base64 value for an integer?

Tags: command-line, base64

I would like to check the [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) value for an integer. There is a `base64` linux command but I don't understand how I can apply it on integers.

I have tried with `base64 10` but then I get the error message `base64: 10: No such file or directory`

I think that the problem can be that Base64 is used for Binary to Textual conversion, so there is no point to pass a Textual argument to it. So my argument `10` is read as an textual string and not as a binary number. Is there any way I can turn a texttual argument to a binary?

How can I use the base64 command to get the Base64 value for an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the number into hex than use `echo` to print the according byte sequence and pipe that into `base64`. So to encode the integer 10 with base64, you can use:

```
echo -en '\xA' | base64
```

To explain the result. The byte 10 has the following binary representation:

```
00001010
```

What base64 does is, it chunks those into groups of 6 bits. So with padding we get the following two 6lets:

```
000010 100000
```

Which in decimal are 2 and 32, which correspond to the letters C and g.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I get wrong result. I get `Cg==` where C=2 and g=32 according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), why is that? Shouldn't it be `K` and maybe some padding with `==`? And a single number in base 10 should be only one number/letter in base 64.

Comment: @Jonas: No, that's exactly the right result. See my explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand this now. But how can I check the Base64 for a number, without using the binary representation that is used by computers (always 32 bit) e.g. using 4 bits for the number ten and no padding. Maybe this isn't possible with the `base64` command. In that way `10` should be `K`. I tried with `echo -en '\b1010' | base64` but it didn't work.

Comment: I mean the base64 implementation referenced as `base64url` on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). But I guess that this isn't available as a command in Bash. So I probably have to find it somewhere or implement it myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jonas: Yeah, you can't really do it. It's not possible to create a file that's less than one byte big (or write less than one byte to a stream or pass a number that's less than one byte big to a function in C - everything is at least one byte in the computer). What you can do is shift the number two bits to the left and then call base64 on that. This will give you two 6lets the latter of which will be 0 and the former will be the number you want.

Comment: @Jonas: I'm not sure why you mention urls all of the sudden. Urls are strings (which still consist of bytes), not integers. So I don't see how 10 becoming K has anything to do with URLs.

Comment: Yes, computers represent integers with fixed 32 bits, but when you convert it to ASCII you can skip leading zeros so `00001010` become `1010`, it is still the same decimal value, `10` and this is possible in computers. I didn't mention URLs but `base64url` that do exactly the encoding I want to do, without the leadin zeros. Simply I want to transform IDs (integer) from a database to the shortest possible ASCII sequence that is compatible with URLs. E.g if the ID is 1223347 that can be represented with only **four** ascii letters using base64url and not **seven** as with int.

Comment: This is common in URL shorteners. See [URL shortener: best encoding method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375968/url-shortener-best-encoding-method/2376044#2376044) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jonas: That's completely wrong. The ASCII string 00001010 is 8 bytes long (i.e. 64 bits). The String 1010 is 4 bytes long. None of those bytes have the value 10.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. The decimal value 10, can be represented with **four bits** `1010` and in computers with **one byte** using four leading zeros `00001010`, both these bit sequences represent the decimal value `10` and can be represented with `K` using `base64url`.

Comment: @Jonas: All of that is correct, except the "and can be represented with K using base64url" bit. The table that maps 10 to K is something that is applied after the byte sequence has been split into 6lets. If the letter K appears in the base64 code that does *not* mean that the number 10 appeared in the original data as a byte, an 32-bit integer, the ASCII string "10" or in any other form. It just means that after splitting into 6lets you got a 10 somewhere.

Comment: No, the algorithm you talk about is `base64` and it works on bytes (bit sequeces fixed to 8 bits), but I talks about `base64url` that works on binary numbers (no fixed length) where decimal `10` is represented by `K`. Clearly I don't want to involve bytes at all.

Comment: @Jonas: base64url works on URLs, which are strings. And the string 10 is encoded as MTA, not K.

Comment: @Jonas: The only difference between base64 and base64url is that base64 will encode the string "10" as MTA=, while base64url will encode it as MTA.

Comment: Okey, if that is the case I have to implement my own `base64notdumb` that just skips the leading zeros.

Comment: @Jonas: I still don't see what you're trying to do. If you're trying to encode an URL, I don't understand why you're talking about numbers all the times, because URLs generally consist out of ASCII characters. If you're trying to do something else, it will probably be helpful if you explain what that is.

Comment: Again, I'm not going to encode URLs, but numbers, and I want them in the shortest possible ASCII compatible with URLs. I will encode the ID (integer) column from a database. So the ID 10 can shortest be represented with `K` using `The Base64 index table`.

Comment: However, it most be much better performance using the algorithm you mention, so I think I'll go with that one. I think that I can convert a `base64` string to a `base64url` by dropping the `=`:s at the end and then replace `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`. Or is there a command in Linux that can convert the base64-string? I can use a regex otherwise. +1 Thanks for a great explaination of `base64` and `base64url`.

Answer (score 0):

The command below converts a decimal integer to radix 64. It does not use the Base64 encoding scheme, but it uses the characters used by the URL-safe variant of the Base64 encoding scheme as digits.

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR-1]=$0;next}{if($0==0){print"A";next}o="";for(n=$0;n!=0;n=int(n/64))o=a[n%64]o;print o}' <(printf %s\\n {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} - _) -`

The command below does the same in Bash. It also works with Zsh if you replace `l%64` with `l%64+1`.

`unset a;a=({A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} - _);while IFS= read l;do if ((l==0));then echo A;continue;fi;o=;for ((;l!=0;l/=64));do o=${a[l%64]}$o;done;printf %s\\n "$o";done`

This converts radix 64 to decimal:

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=NR-1;next}{o=0;for(i=NF;i>=1;i--)o+=a[$i]*64^(NF-i);print o}' FS= <(printf %s\\n {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} - _) -`

This does the same in Bash:

`unset a;i=0;declare -A a;for x in {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} - _;do a[$x]=$((i++));done;while IFS= read l;do o=0;for((i=${#l};i>=1;i--));do let o+=${a[${l:i-1:1}]}*64**(${#l}-i);done;echo "$o";done`

The `awk` commands result in loss of precision with `2**53+1` and larger numbers, but to avoid it you can add `-M` (`--bignum`) in `gawk` 4.1 and later.

The Bash commands result in integer overflow with `2**63` and larger numbers.