# How can I create a file that just contains a binary number?

Tags: command-line, file-command

I would like to create a file that just contains a binary number. I think that `touch` can be used to create an empty file, but is there any way I can fill it with a binary number e.g. `10` (ten)? And how can I validate that the file contains the binary value of ten?

See also [How can I check the Base64 value for an integer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-can-i-check-the-base64-value-for-an-integer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the number to hex (in this case `A`) and then do:

```
echo -en '\xA' > file
```

Comment: Thanks, however, now I don't know how I can validate this anser. E.g could I write the number 65 and in some way print that with a command?

Comment: @Jonas: `hexdump file` will display the bytes in a file as hex.

Comment: Thanks for `hexdump`. I added that to my question. However I don't think echoing the hexnumber is working. When I look at the file with `hexdump file` I get `0000000 785c 0041 0000003` and I get a different value for `echo -n '\xa` > file`

Comment: The file seems to contain something more than a number, and with `hexdump` should the hexvalue `\xA` be shown as `A` or `a`? But it doesn't in this case.

Comment: @Jonas: Ok, my bad. I tested this in `zsh` and apparently zsh's `echo` behaves differently than bash's. In bash you need the `-e` option to echo for `\x` to work.

Comment: When I do `hexdump file` I get two lines, one with `0000000 000a` and that is clearly one address and the integer 10, but the second line is only `0000001`, what doeas this mean, is there a `EOF` or is it just a way by `hexdump` to show the end of file? Or is there something more than the four byte integer in the file?

Comment: @Jonas: It's just how `hexdump` displays the file.

Comment: In bash, you could confirm the number that you put into the file using something like: `printf '%d' $(hexdump -v -e '/1 "0x%02x"' file)`

Comment: Also, you can do the conversion to hex in-line, like so: `echo -ne $(printf '\\x%x' 10) > file`

Comment: @sepp2k Just use `printf`, it's more portable.